# Center striped backgrounds in css

Tags: css

Trying to create a background like this

[image: Center striped image]

Is it possible with CSS?

Comment: Is it possible to create a background with gradients that looks like the image above?

Comment: I tried with radial gradients @Paulie_D. But I couldn't create the yellow stripes with varying width that starts from center

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. You can use `repeating-conic-gradient`.

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  background: repeating-conic-gradient(
    hsla(0,0%,100%,.2) 0deg 15deg,
    hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 0deg 30deg
  ) #ccb300;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You read more about it at [W3 CSS Image Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-4/#example-34b67cf2).
This property is not compatible with all browsers. Check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-conic-gradients)  for more information.